# Already generated plots missing in Show

Tags: plotting, legending

```
p6 = Plot[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(50\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(\((2*\ k + 1)\)*\ \[Pi]\)] 4\ *1 (*c0*) *
     MittagLefflerE[0.5 (*\[Beta]*) , \((\(-0.1\) (*D*) *\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((2\ *k + 1)\), \(2\)]\ *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]\ *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(\(0.5\)\( (*\[Beta]*) \)\)])\)]\ *
     Sin[\((2\ *k + 1)\)*\ \[Pi]*\ 0.5 (*x*) ]\)\), {t, 0, 10}];
p7 = Plot[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(50\)]\(\((
\*FractionBox[\(4*1 (*c0*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \((\(-0.002\) (*D*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\((2*k + 1)\), \(2\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]*t)\)]\), \(\((2*k + 
          1)\)*\[Pi]\)])\)*Sin[\((2*k + 1)\)*\[Pi]*0.5]\)\), {t, 0, 
    10}];
p8 = Plot[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(50\)]\(\((
\*FractionBox[\(4*1 (*c0*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \((\(-0.0025\) (*D*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\((2*k + 1)\), \(2\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]*t)\)]\), \(\((2*k + 
          1)\)*\[Pi]\)])\)*Sin[\((2*k + 1)\)*\[Pi]*0.5]\)\), {t, 0, 
    10}];
p9 = Plot[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(50\)]\(\((
\*FractionBox[\(4*1 (*c0*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \((\(-0.003\) (*D*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\((2*k + 1)\), \(2\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]*t)\)]\), \(\((2*k + 
          1)\)*\[Pi]\)])\)*Sin[\((2*k + 1)\)*\[Pi]*0.5]\)\), {t, 0, 
    10}];
p10 = Plot[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(50\)]\(\((
\*FractionBox[\(4*1 (*c0*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \((\(-0.0035\) (*D*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\((2*k + 1)\), \(2\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]*t)\)]\), \(\((2*k + 
          1)\)*\[Pi]\)])\)*Sin[\((2*k + 1)\)*\[Pi]*0.5]\)\), {t, 0, 
    10}];
p11 = Plot[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(50\)]\(\((
\*FractionBox[\(4*1 (*c0*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \((\(-0.004\) (*D*) *
\*SuperscriptBox[\((2*k + 1)\), \(2\)]*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]*t)\)]\), \(\((2*k + 
          1)\)*\[Pi]\)])\)*Sin[\((2*k + 1)\)*\[Pi]*0.5]\)\), {t, 0, 
    10}];
Show[p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

I would like to combine the above plots using the`Show` command. However, only one curve appears in the output.

[image]

Furthermore, no legend is visible. What is the problem?

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All` to your `Show` expression. In Show the PlotRange settings are inherited from the first plot in the list, and that choice just happens to cut out all other plots. `Show[p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: Please take a look at [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951) so you can past readable code in your future questions.

Comment: Code like this is unreadable. You should know that by not taking care of sharing reasonably formatted code in `InputForm`, you are alienating many experienced people that could otherwise help find a good answer.

Comment: @MarcoB，your link helps me better format my code.

Answer (score 5):

```
f6 = Sum[(1/((2*k + 1)*Pi))*4*1*
         MittagLefflerE[0.5, -0.1*(2*k + 1)^2*
             Pi^2*t^0.5]*Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], 
       {k, 0, 50}]; 
f7 = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.002*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*
                    t)*((2*k + 1)*Pi)))*
         Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 
f8 = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.0025*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*
                    t)*((2*k + 1)*Pi)))*
         Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 
f9 = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.003*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*
                    t)*((2*k + 1)*Pi)))*
         Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 
f10 = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.0035*(2*k + 1)^2*
                    Pi^2*t)*((2*k + 1)*Pi)))*
         Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 
f11 = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.004*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*
                    t)*((2*k + 1)*Pi)))*
         Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}];
Plot[Evaluate@{f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, AxesOrigin ->  {0, 0}
 , PlotLegends -> {
   Placed[
    LineLegend[ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[2, 6]~Join~{1}, 
     "f" <> ToString@# & /@ Range[7, 11]~Join~{6}
     ]
    , After]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-II**

If you want to put the legend inside the picture, and experiment with "Row", "Column", their count and position then you can modify the following. Here I have put the legend just to the right (1.05) of plot and half way on the vertical scale (0.55).

```
PlotLegends -> {
  Placed[LineLegend[ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[2, 6]~Join~{1}, 
    "f" <> ToString@# & /@ Range[7, 11]~Join~{6}
    , LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}
    ]
   , {1.05, 0.55}]
  }
```

Comment: Code like this is unreadable.

Comment: Thanks Syed. the code for legend is a tough work.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define separate functions rather than separate plots.

```
f[1] = Sum[(1/((2*k + 1)*Pi))*4*1*MittagLefflerE[0.5, 
           -0.1*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*t^0.5]*Sin[(2*k + 1)*
             Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 

f[2] = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.002*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*t)*((2*k + 1)*
                  Pi)))*Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 

f[3] = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.0025*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*t)*((2*k + 1)*
                  Pi)))*Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 

f[4] = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.003*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*t)*((2*k + 1)*
                  Pi)))*Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 

f[5] = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.0035*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*t)*((2*k + 1)*
                  Pi)))*Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}]; 

f[6] = Sum[((4*1)/(E^(0.004*(2*k + 1)^2*Pi^2*t)*((2*k + 1)*
                  Pi)))*Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*0.5], {k, 0, 50}];
```

Use a single [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). For comparison I use both [`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html) and [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html), you would most likely only use one or the other.

```
Plot[Evaluate[f /@ Range[6]], {t, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLabels -> (Subscript[f, #] & /@ Range[6]),
 PlotLegends -> (Subscript[f, #] & /@ Range[6])]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob. your logical, specific code helps me a lot. I want to mark the plot-Labels inside the picture frame, and I try some options which doesn't work.